# Universal reference with templated class

Tags: c++, templates, universal-reference

Example:

```
template <typename T>
class Bar
{
public:
    void foo(T&& arg)
    {
        std::forward<T>(arg);
    }
};

Bar<int> bar;    

bar.foo(10); // works

int a{ 10 };
bar.foo(a); // error C2664: cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'int &&'
```

It seems that universal references works **only** with templated functions and **only** with type deduction, right? So it make no sense to use it with class? And does using of `std::forward` makes sense in my case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note that the preferred terminology (i.e. the one which will be in future versions of the spec) is now *forwarding reference*.

As you say, a forwarding reference only works with type deduction in a function template. In your case, when you say `T&&`, `T` is `int`. It can't be `int&` because it has been explicitly stated in your `Bar` instantiation. As such, reference-collapsing rules can't occur, so you can't do perfect forwarding.

If you want to do perfect forwarding in a member function like that, you need to have a member function template:

```
template <typename U>
void foo(U&& arg)
{
    std::forward<U>(arg); //actually do something here
}
```

If you absolutely need `U` to have the same unqualified type as `T`, you can do a `static_assert`:

```
template <typename U>
void foo(U&& arg)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<std::decay_t<U>,std::decay_t<T>>::value, 
                  "U must be the same as T");
    std::forward<U>(arg); //actually do something here
}
```

`std::decay` might be a bit too aggressive for you as it will decay array types to pointers. If that's not what you want, you could write your own simple trait:

```
template <typename T>
using remove_cv_ref = std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;

template <typename T, typename U>
using is_equiv = std::is_same<remove_cv_ref<T>, remove_cv_ref<U>>;
```

If you need a variadic version, we can write an `are_equiv` trait. First we need a trait to check if all traits in a pack are true. I'll use the `bool_pack` method:

```
namespace detail
{
    template<bool...> struct bool_pack;
    template<bool... bs>
    using all_true = std::is_same<bool_pack<bs..., true>, bool_pack<true, bs...>>;
}
template <typename... Ts>
using all_true = detail::all_true<Ts::value...>;
```

Then we need something to check if each pair of types in `Ts...` and `Us...` satisfy `is_equiv`. We can't take two parameter packs as template arguments, so I'll use std::tuple to separate them (you could use a sentinel node, or split the pack halfway through instead if you wanted):

```
template <typename TTuple, typename UTuple>
struct are_equiv;

template <typename... Ts, typename... Us>
struct are_equiv <std::tuple<Ts...>, std::tuple<Us...>> : all_true<is_equiv<Ts,Us>...>
{};
```

Then we can use this like:

```
static_assert(are_equiv<std::tuple<Ts...>,std::tuple<Us...>>::value, 
              "Us must be equivalent to Ts");
```

Comment: Thank you. `static_assert` is good for me. Is there something similar I can use with variadic template arguments in standard library?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Something similar to `static_assert` that takes multiple arguments?

Comment: Exactly. I have a class with `template <typename... T>` and a function which I want to declare as `foo(U&&... args)`. So I need to compare both T and U. I can write a helper, but maybe it's already done in stl. I just can't find it.

Comment: Updated my answer with a possible solution.

Comment: Wow, that's looks really scary. Unfortunately I'm not able to understand this magic symbols (btw, can you please advise some good reference where I can learn this advanced stuff?). All I can say - it doesn't compiles with VS2013. It gives me an error `'std::is_same<remove_cv<_Ty>::type,remove_cv<remove_reference<Us>::type>::type>...'`

Comment: I'm probably using some language features not supported in VS2013, or hitting a compiler bug. As far as references are concerned, the best way to understand this stuff is just to try it out, look at other posts tagged `c++` and `templates`, etc.

Answer (score 5):

You're right : "universal references" only appear when the type of a *deduced* parameter is `T&&`. In your case, there is no deduction (`T` is known from the class), hence no universal reference.

In your snippet, `std::forward` will always perform `std::move` as `arg` is a regular rvalue reference.

If you wish to generate a universal reference, you need to make `foo` a function template :

```
template <typename T>
class Bar
{
public:
    template <typename U>
    void foo(U&& arg)
    {
        std::forward<U>(arg);
    }
};
```

Comment: It `T` is `int&` your conclusion doesn't hold, pr at least is ambiguous.  Can you clarify what you are trying to say woth you say "they only appear", and demonstrate that forwarding references aren't super magic?

Comment: @Yakk To my knowledge, "universal (or forwarding) reference" is the name given to the intersection of type deduction, rvalue references and reference collapsing. I admittedly didn't consider the case where `T` itself is a reference. Is it still a forwarding reference if the forwarded object is *always* of reference type ?

Comment: Yakk's point is that if `T` is `int&`, arg will be of type `int&` as well, i.e. referencing collapsing rules will apply, but it's not a forwarding reference because it's not in a deduced context.

Comment: And a relatively standard use is to deduce a type into a type.  Use a helper function to produce `T` in deduction, instantiate `foo_t<T>`.  Splits deduction from use, but...