# Why does `std::make_tuple` require move semantics?

Tags: c++, stdtuple

I think it's a pretty conscious design decision to make the creation of a `std::tuple` through `std::make_tuple` require rvalue reference arguments (type `T&&`).

However, this implies [move semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics) [(std::move is little more than a cast to `T&&`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413470/what-is-stdmove-and-when-should-it-be-used/42340735#42340735) for object types, and I'm not really comfortable with construction of a `std::tuple` always requiring that.

```
int x = 7, y = 5;
std::tuple<int, int> fraction = make_tuple<int, int>( x, y ); // fails
```

About the above, the compiler says:

> error C2664: 'std::tuple<int,int> std::make_tuple<int,int>(int &&,int &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'int &&'
>
> message : You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference

You can make a `std::tuple` from lvalues no problem if you don't use `make_tuple`:

```
std::tuple<int, int> fraction = { x, y }; // ok
```

My question is, why is this?

Comment: `T&&` in a template is not an rvalue reference, it is a forwarding reference, which can bind to lvalues and rvalues.

Comment: You'd need to use `std::make_tuple<int&, int&>( x, y );` because `make_tuple` uses forwarding references. But in practice you would just use `std::make_tuple( x, y );` and let template argument deduction do the work for you.

Comment: Explicitly specifying the parameters of `make_tuple` loses its original purpose.

Comment: @康桓瑋 How so? What was its original purpose?

Comment: I see also that `std::tuple<int, int> fraction = make_tuple(x, y);` works

Comment: @bobobobo add an `auto`, and it becomes clear how it leads to much cleaner/smaller code: `auto fraction = std::make_tuple(x, y);`

Comment: @bobobobo You can create a tuple with explicit types with `tuple<A,B>(a,b)`, no need for `make_tuple`. The whole point of `make_tuple` is to let the compiler deduce the types. (later came some changes so we can use plain `tuple` like `make_tuple`)

Comment: tuple uses std::forward<T> not std::move

Answer (score 8):

`std::make_tuple` doesn't take an rvalue reference to a `T`, contrary to what it seems; it takes a universal reference to a `T` (`T&&`). If universal reference is new to you, let me explain.

The definition of `make_tuple` looks more or less like this:

```
template<typename... Ts>
std::tuple<Ts...> make_tuple(Ts&&... ts){ 
    // ... 
}
```

But for purposes of explanation, I am going to refer to `make_tuple` like this:

```
template<typename T>
std::tuple<T> make_tuple(T&& t){ 
    // ... 
}
```

Using type deduction, when `make_tuple` is passed an rvalue (lets say an `int&&`), the type deduced for `T` is `int`, since make_tuple takes a T&& and it was passed an rvalue. The definition of `make_tuple` (with `T` deduced) now looks like this:

```
std::tuple<int> make_tuple(int&& t){ 
    // ... 
}
```

Here is where things get confusing: if `make_tuple` is passed an lvalue `int`, what should `T` be deduced as? The compiler deduces `T` as `int&` and uses something called [reference collapsing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference).

Reference collapsing basically states that if the compiler forms a reference to a reference and one of them is lvalue, then the resulting reference is lvalue. Otherwise else, it is an rvalue reference.

The definition of `make_tuple` (with `T` deduced) now looks like this:

```
std::tuple<int&> make_tuple(int& && t){ 
    // ... 
}
```

Which collapses to:

```
std::tuple<int&> make_tuple(int& t){ 
    // ... 
}
```

So, back to your failed example:

```
std::tuple<int, int> fraction = make_tuple<int, int>( x, y );
```

Let's see what `make_tuple` looks like:

```
// since you explicitly called make_tuple<int,int>(), then no deduction occurs
std::tuple<int,int> make_tuple(int&& t1, int&& t2){ // Error! rvalue reference cannot bind to lvalue
    // ... 
}
```

*Now* it becomes clear why your example doesn't work. Since no reference collapsing occured, then `T&&` stayed `int&&`.

A revised version of your code should look something like this:

```
auto fraction = std::make_tuple(x,y);
```

I hope I explained this well.

Comment: Very good answer. But imho what is missing is showing how `std::tuple` is supposed to be used, i.e. without explicit template parameter.

Comment: My take on how `std::tuple` is supposed to be used is that it isn't. With structured binding and `std::make_tuple` + CTAD, the use-cases for a plain `std::tuple` has diminished greatly. Oh, and lambdas also helped diminish their prominence.

Comment: Do the same rules apply when calling the tuple constructor directly? It looks like calling the tuple constructor in the same way with explicitly specified types compiles just fine.

Comment: @user21796467 No, `std::tuple<Types...>` has a constructor which takes `const Types&...`. Also see see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30569454/universal-reference-with-templated-class).

Comment: @user21796467 sorry for the typo haha. I hope I've answered your question?